# Checking if a variable is a number in R

Tags: r

I have following data frame:

```
> ddf = data.frame(name=c('a','b'), value=c(10,20))
> ddf
  name value
1    a    10
2    b    20
```

I try to get xx from ddf using following command:

```
> xx = ddf[ddf$name=='a','value']
> xx
[1] 10
> xx = ddf[ddf$name=='c','value']
> xx
numeric(0)
```

How can I test if xx is a valid number and not 'numeric(0)'. I tried following:

```
> is.numeric(xx)
[1] TRUE
> is.na(xx)
logical(0)
> is.null(xx)
[1] FALSE
> is.logical(xx)
[1] FALSE
```

I have to ask for `xx = ddf[ddf$name=='a', 'value']` from different `ddf` data frames. Sometimes `ddf` does not contain `'a'` and hence no value is returned. I want to detect this.

Comment: Note however that "valid number" is not a parameter in `R`. What if you don't want to allow `NA` or `Inf` values?  Make sure you know exactly what you need to test for!

Comment: You could check its length

Comment: I have edited my question for what exactly I need. I think length(xx)>0 will be best.

Comment: @rnso - The `> 0` isn't necessary because `0` is a logical `FALSE`, and any other number is always `TRUE`. So `if(!length(x))` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to do this using base R is to check the length of `xx`.

```
if(length(xx)>0)
  {
  <do something>
  }
```

If you want to check that the variable is also numeric use `is.numeric`

```
if (length(xx)>0 & is.numeric(xx))
```

For instance, taking your example:

```
xx <- ddf[ddf$name=='a','value']

is.numeric(xx) & length(xx)>0
[1] TRUE


xx <- ddf[ddf$name=='c','value']

is.numeric(xx) & length(xx)>0
[1] FALSE


xx <- ddf[ddf$name=='a','name']

is.numeric(xx) & length(xx)>0
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: That only verifies there's "something there,"  but not that it's `numeric` rather than some other class, so this needs to be in addition to , not instead of, the OP's code.  Just wanted to clarify that point.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft depending on the situation that may or may not be an issue, anyway, I updated the code.

Answer (score 9):

The following code uses regular expressions to confirm that the character string on contains numeric digits and has at least a single digit.  See below:

```
grepl("^[0-9]{1,}$", xx)
```

Or if you need to deal with negative numbers and decimal places:

```
grepl("^[-]{0,1}[0-9]{0,}.{0,1}[0-9]{1,}$", xx)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
library(assertive)
is_a_number(xx)          # returns TRUE or FALSE
assert_is_a_number(xx)   # throws an error if not TRUE
```

This combines two tests.  Firstly it checks that `xx` has class `numeric` (`integer` is OK too, since the underlying check is done by `is.numeric`), and secondly it checks that the length of `xx` is one.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this where you just check the number of resulting rows after filtering?

```
library(tidyverse)
ddf = data.frame(name=c('a','b'), value=c(10,20))
t <- ddf %>% filter(name == "c")
nrow(t) == 0
[1] TRUE
```